# Why SHA1 and SHA256 are not matching with my app package name?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, sha1

I am working on Two  different flutter projects and i am trying to authentication my apps using Firebase phone number authentication method,  and one of the requirement is to add a SHA1 AND SHA256 fingerprint, So here is issue i am facing, when i try generate a fingerprint certificates a (SHA1 AND SHA256) i just get the same key for bother app, i am just asking myself why i am getting the same key with the different project?

And The big issue is that When i configured them on Firebase console, my first app worked fine and the other not,

Basically i am using the same (SHA1 AND SHA256) for both app

1: I need help, why the (SHA1 AND SHA256) are the same when generated on different projects
2: How can i get a unique (SHA1 AND SHA256) for an individual app:

I tried to add a (SHA1 AND SHA256)  first app it did well for sure

But the second gave me an error message of

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SekA9.png)

Comment: Post your error as text, not as an image.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Are you using the same keystore for both apps by any chance? Can you show how you "generate" the fingerprints? (I assume you're actually just accessing them from the keystore)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: check your two apk use same key store?

Comment: Thanks for reacting to my post, i am actually using " keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore"  for generating a fingerprint in debug

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a debug keys, it remain same for all apps run in your system. Once you upload your app on playstore, there you will find release SHA1 and SHA-256 keys which will be unique for all apps.

Comment: Thanks for replaying, yes, agree, but the first app works fine from what you same the other does not work using app  same SHA1 and SHA-256.  End up getting This app is not authorized to use Firebase error.

Answer (score 0):

Run Task :app:signingReport for Release variant you will get unique key.